# Using Lego Digital Designer and Blender

Tags: snapping, ldd

From what I heard, I think that the Lego Movie made their lego models in LDD, and than exporting the models to Maya, and using maya to make subsurf models.  I think that they found a way to make their subsurf models automatically be placed in the correct place using data from LDD?  Does anyone know how to do this?  (I realize it's a hefty topic)

Comment: Lego Digital Designer allows to export ldraw files. You could try the following add-on (I haven't tested it): https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw

Comment: the addon works really well!  This may solve all my problems! I'll leave the question open for now, in case I need to make any manual parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Lego Digitial Designer manual](https://www.lego.com/r/www/r/ldd/-/media/franchises/ldd2017/support/ldd%204%203%20en-manual.pdf?l.r2=1264289309) it allows to export LXF, LXFML and LDraw files.

> **Export.** Export lets you create LXF, LXFML and LDraw files that can be
>   opened in other applications

There are community developed Blender add-ons such as [ImportLDraw by Toby Nelson](https://github.com/TobyLobster/ImportLDraw) that allow to import these models.

Comment: I just realized that the addon also adds a bevel modifier to each piece, and it makes a great result. :)

Comment: I'll award the bounty to you when i can, it won't let me yet

Comment: Glad that it's what you're looking for. No problem. BTW his name seems to be Toby *Nelson* not *Lobster*, at least according to his profile: https://github.com/TobyLobster The lobster is just part of his username.